# is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: sbt, appveyor

[sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager) is using appveyor to test the `WindowsPlugin` for generating msi packages. Since a few days all our builds start to fail because `sbt` is no longer found.

This is the [appveyor.yml](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/appveyor.yml)

```
version: '{build}'
os: Windows Server 2012
install:
  - ps: |
      Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
      if (!(Test-Path -Path "C:\sbt" )) {
        (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile(
          'https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/native-packages/sbt/0.13.7/sbt-0.13.7.zip',
          'C:\sbt-bin.zip'
        )
        [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory("C:\sbt-bin.zip", "C:\sbt")
      }
  - cmd: SET PATH=C:\sbt\sbt\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
  - cmd: SET SBT_OPTS=-XX:MaxPermSize=2g -Xmx4g
build_script:
  - sbt clean compile
test_script:
  - sbt "test-only * -- -n windows"
  - sbt "scripted universal/dist universal/stage windows/*"
cache:
  - C:\sbt\
  - C:\Users\appveyor\.m2
  - C:\Users\appveyor\.ivy2
```

An example build can be found [here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/muuki88/sbt-native-packager/build/562). Has anything changed on appveyor's side? We haven't changed anything on ours.

cheers,
Muki

Answer (score 1):

I believe this was another manifestation of [this](https://github.com/appveyor/ci/issues/1202) bug, which was fixed over weekend. Could you please try now?

Comment: Thanks. I tried to rebuild the PR and master, but with no effect. The error still remains. I'll take a look if this has something to do with the env variables mentioned in the ticket.